# Facebook FBui  'stream.publish' to single friend (help needed) 

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-graph-api, stream, facebook-java-api

I am having trouble getting code correct to have user (of my app) post to friend's wall. I want user to be able to pick single friend and post to thier stream. What am I missing to have the user select 1 friend from list, or type friends name? This is my "post" function that I can't get to work. It works when the method is 'feed' to post to the user's wall. But method as 'stream.publish' it still functions like 'feed' and posts to user's wall.

```
     function pubStream(obj,gift_id,item_name)
     {
     FB.ui({
            method: 'stream.publish',
            display: 'popup',     //have tried display:iframe does same             
            name: "Special Delivery!",
            link: "<?php echo $app_info['transfer_protocol']; ?>apps.facebook.com/<?php echo $app_info['canvas']; ?>/?friendID="+facebook_id+"&giftID="+gift_id,
            picture: "<?php echo $app_info['upload_url']; ?>"+obj,
            caption: "//not used at this time ",
            description: "my item escription",
            message: "user's message ",
            actions: {"name":"my items name","link":"<?php echo $app_info['transfer_protocol']; ?>apps.facebook.com/<?php echo $app_info['canvas']; ?>/?friendID="+facebook_id+"&giftID="+gift_id}
    },function(response){hideLightbox();});
  }
```

Comment: @Coulton thanks, I was looking for a way to actually post on a friends wall BUT this will accomplish same goal. Except, the issue I have now is. Sense this is a 'gift' app the links( to accept gift) are broke in a message. Is there a way to embed the request in the message? Sense the message isnt a 'apprequest' or 'feed' the $_REQUEST[] array isnt called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the 'send' User Interface.

There are docs on this here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

It's practically the same code as your feed dialog, except the user can specify which friends they want to communicate it to.

Assuming your code is correct this would work:

```
function pubStream(obj,gift_id,item_name)
     {
     FB.ui({
            method: 'send',
            display: 'popup',     //have tried display:iframe does same             
            name: "Special Delivery!",
            link: "<?php echo $app_info['transfer_protocol']; ?>apps.facebook.com/<?php echo $app_info['canvas']; ?>/?friendID="+facebook_id+"&giftID="+gift_id,
            picture: "<?php echo $app_info['upload_url']; ?>"+obj,
            caption: "//not used at this time ",
            description: "my item escription",
            message: "user's message ",
            actions: {"name":"my items name","link":"<?php echo $app_info['transfer_protocol']; ?>apps.facebook.com/<?php echo $app_info['canvas']; ?>/?friendID="+facebook_id+"&giftID="+gift_id}
    },function(response){hideLightbox();});
  }
```

You just choose `method: 'send'` and then use the properties shown on the 'feed' documentation, here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/